# IntelliJ IDEA 14.03 failed to browse JDK 1.8 source code

Tags: intellij-14

I added the latest JDK 1.8 into my projects in IntelliJ IDEA 14.03. But later I found that I can't jump to the source code of any class from JDK. IntelliJ always using the internal java decompiler showing the source code decompiled from .class, even I manually disable the decompiler plugin!

When I switch back to Oracle JDK 1.7, everyting is fine.

Anyone has the same issue?

I am using MacOS 10.10.2(Yosemite)

Answer (score 0):

I found the anwser. After "Invalid cache and restart", everything is working again.